# Почему в Laravel не подключается header?

Tags: php, laravel

routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', 'MasterController@index');
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('header');
});
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('footer');
});
```

MasterController.php:

```
class MasterController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{
   return view('master');
}
```

header.blade.php:

```
@extends('master')

@section('header')

    <h1> HEADER</h1>
@endsection
```

master.blade.php:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1> @yield('header')</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        @yield('footer')
    </div>
</body>
```

footer.php:

```
  @extends('master')

  @section('footer')

     <h1>FOOTER</h1>

  @endsection
```

результат должно быть две надписи "HEADER" и "FOOTER"...так вот выводит только   "FOOTER"...ПОЧЕМУ так?в роутах же они одинаково прописаны то...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не совсем видимо верно поняли значение @yield и спутали его с @include

@yield - это динамическая вставка так сказать, будет заполнена только тогда, когда в вызываемом шаблоне описаны section('footer'),section('header')

@include - скажем так статическая вставка, при помощи @include вы можете разделить footer, header, menu, для удобства правки

Если вы хотите создать шаблон он будет выглядеть так:

layout.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    @include('header')

    <div id="content">
      @yield('content')
    </div>

    @include('footer')

</body>
</html>
```

header.blade.php

```
<header>
   <div class="banner"></div>
   <h1>@yield('title') </h1>
</header>
```

footer.blade.php

```
 <footer>
      Здесь футер
    </footer>
```

И например страница:
page.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')

 @section('title') Заголовок который пойдет в H1 @endsection

 @section('content') 
   Основной текст страницы
 @endsection
```

B вот теперь в контроллере вызов шаблона page

```
public function index()
{
   return view('page');
}
```

даст вам footer, header и контент

Comment: Вы написали "content" в файле layout.php, а в page.php написали "context", я изменил и все работает!

Comment: Ага....спасибо огромное, теперь я понял свою глобальную ошибку!!!)))

Comment: @Александр ага поправил :)